# Bootstrap Modal Does Not Re-Open By Key After Closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So i currently have the following code for a twitter bootstrap modal:

```
   <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="confirm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="margin: auto; margin-top: 60px; cursor: pointer;">
        Confirm
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered w3-animate-bottom" style="max-width: 1000px !important;">
          <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius: 10px; padding: 20px;">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: white; color: black; text-align: center;">
              <h3 style="padding: 8px;"><strong>Confirm Credentials</strong></h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <strong>Borrower ID:</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">

                  </div>
                  <div class="w-100"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: white; color: black;">
              <div class="text-center" id="footmsg" style="float: left; text-align: left;">
                <p>Are you sure you want to submit?</p>
              </div>
              <span style="width: 20px;"></span>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              <button type="button submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitter" style="cursor: pointer;">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and I tried to handle the part where I can launch the modal via the enter key by JQuery. This is the code:

```
    $(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
        var key=event.which;
        if (key==13) {
             $('#confirm').click();
        }
    });
```

what it basically does is that it clicks the button that is supposed to launch the supposed modal. So I tried it and it worked the first time. However, when I clicked on the buttons inside the modal that would dismiss the modal, upon trying to press enter again, nothing happens. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure the button _#confirm_ has focus after the dialog is dismissed? What appened if you click on it with the mouse?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events

Comment: @MarioSantini I'm not really sure about it but it works if I click anywhere on the page first then after pressing enter, it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Apparently, based on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/ there is a .modal('show') function that gets things done how I wanted it.